# How to use slicers in Power Pivot on many-to-many relationships?

Tags: excel, many-to-many, powerpivot, slicers

I have a Power Pivot model (in Excel 2016) with Curators, Pupils, and Assignments of curators to pupils. The goal is to produce a pivot table with a list of curators sorted by their number of assignments. Basically this a simple requirement, easy to set up. But then I would like to add slicers for filtering the list, according to criteria that are many-to-many :

- a curator may speak one or several foreign languages
- a curator may have several "preferred assignments" (only adults, only children, only juridical matters, personal assistance, etc.)

I have read how to deal with many-to-many relationships in *measures* (well explained in https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/many-to-many-relationships-in-power-bi-and-excel-2016/). But is there a way to use *slicers* on such relationships ?

Here is a fake dataset that illustrates the problem : we have **composers**

```
Cid Name
B   Bach
M   Mozart
H   Haydn
```

They created **works**

```
Cid Work
B   Johannes-Passion
B   Mattheus-Passion
B   H-Moll Messe
B   Well-Tempered
M   Cosi fan tutte
M   Requiem
H   The Seasons
H   Die Schöpfung
H   Il Mondo della Luna
```

We can easily compute a pivot table of how many works per composer

```
Étiquettes de lignes    Nombre de Work
Bach    4
Haydn   3
Mozart  2
Total général   9
```

Now there is a **language** table

```
Lid Language
DE  Deutsch
IT  Italiano
EN  English
FR  Français
```

And some composers speak some languages

```
Cid Lid
B   DE
M   DE
M   IT
M   FR
H   DE
H   EN
```

Now I would like to filter the pivot table by a segment on languages
[image: printscreen of pivot table with an added segment]

but it doesn't work because the filter direction from ComposerLanguage to Composer is in the wrong direction
[image: printscreen of the Power Pivot model]

Comment: Provided your slicers are based on the bridge tables which you have set-up as part of your relationship model, I don't see why this should not be reasonably straightforward. As always, a small example dataset with expected results would help.

Comment: Can you post a data sample? Typically, many-to-many relations are properly resolved in dimensional models via fact tables. If that's not the case, you might have an incorrect data model.

Comment: It's a data model issue. You can solve this with DAX tricks, but then you will be sweeping the problem under the rug. I think the key here is missing relations between the languages composers speak and the languages used in the works. Let's say, Bach speaks 2 languages and writes 2 works. Which language was used for which work? This question can not be answered with your data. There are several solutions, depending on what you really want - when you slice works by language, what question are you trying to answer?

Comment: @RADO: thanks for your comment, but no, there is no semantic relationship between works and languages. I just want to reduce the displayed data; suppose there are 5000 composers in the table, the goal is  to dynamically select those who speak a given language (and for each of those composers, show how many works he has composed).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676901/how-to-filter-on-m2m-table-in-dax/51681469#51681469
Ignore the first part of the answer. All DAX approaches will work for you in Excel 2016.